# Stuck On "Detecting Android-x86.. found at dev/sda1" While installing Android 9.1-r2 (x64) In VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, windows-8.1, android, android-x86

**First of all, I'm frustrated as hell, I'm facing this problem for the last 6 months when I first thought to try android on a PC.**

Till then, I've tried multiple iso's from android 7 to android 9 but nothing worked, even the persistence version isn't running. Everytime same error and the same never-ending blinking cursor.

I'm posting here as the last hope, and I don't even know how this forum works but I'm just putting this in front of you all!

So, first of all, I've tried both manual & automatic ways of installing Android 9 (and all previous versions) I've even tried all those basic tweaks like changing "Acceleration" to "KVM", setting "Graphics Control" to VBoxVGA & VBoxSVGA and I've even tried checking/unchecking "3D Acceleration", and all other little tweaks like that (basically I've viewed and applied every Youtube method you can find).

This might give you a rough idea of my knowledge in this installation process. Check the below screenshots for better understanding:

[VirtualBox Configs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REpmo.jpg)

[Trying to Add nomodeset xforcevesa](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVgyU.jpg)

[Never-ending error that I'm facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/030zO.jpg)

[Result In Debug Mode (it just stop there)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGTsX.jpg)

[Even Edit Method Didn't Work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCkcJ.jpg)

[Even Host VT Is Enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3ahh.jpg)

> Host PC: Windows 8.1 x64 (VT Enabled)
> -- Virtual Box Version: 6.1.28 -- ISO: Android-x86_64-9.0-r2 (921 MB)

If any of you guys can help please I'm here. I'm new to this Linux world and I don't want to be discouraged by the cold, unresponsive community question. And if someone is going to respond with "try installing it again!" than please don't even bother to respond!!!

**I've roughly installed & tried it 205 TIMES!!!**

Regards,
Sunny

Comment: Would downloading preinstalled VM images be an option? https://www.osboxes.org/android-x86/ https://www.linuxvmimages.com/images/android-x86/ Have you looked at https://groups.google.com/g/remix-os-for-pc/c/WkYQ8xFKFvA

Comment: Now that's a smart answer. Let me test this one. I'll be back soon.

Comment: I do remember having seen exactly this question some days ago. Why have you posted it again?

Comment: Duplicate of https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/242627/stuck-on-detecting-android-x86-found-at-dev-sda1-while-installing-android-9 same user name but different account.

Comment: I'm new to all this and I think I've posted it multiple times but still, nothing is working.

Comment: Don't know what you want this for, but I have found a dedicated emulator saved me some headaches. [BlueStacks](https://www.bluestacks.com/) is one I have had success with in the past. Essentially, I downloaded it, then replaced the launcher (UI), since I didn't care for it or the pre-installed apps.

Comment: So, I've tested preinstalled iso but still, it's stuck at the same point.

Comment: @Sunny And did you try the advice in the groups.google.com link I posted above? That seemed to fix it for a bunch of people.